# Rendering multiple layers of tiles

Tags: java, tiles, slick2d

I have a little problem, when I try to draw multiple layers of tiles in my game, only the top layer shows up. For example, I have a for loop to draw air tiles, and below that I have another to draw stone tiles. Only the air tiles will draw, the stone tiles won't no matter what I do. Heres my map class:

```
public class Map {

public static final int CLEAR = 0;
public static final int STONE = 1;
public static final int GRASS = 2;
public static final int DIRT = 3;

public static final int WIDTH = 32;
public static final int HEIGHT = 24;

public static final int TILE_SIZE = 25;

static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(WIDTH * HEIGHT);

Image air, grass, stone, dirt;

public Map() {

    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> yaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            yaxis.add(CLEAR);
        }
        map.add(yaxis);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> yaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            yaxis.add(STONE);
        }
        map.add(yaxis);
    }

    try {
        init(null, null);
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    render(null, null, null);

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    air = new Image("res/air.png");
    grass = new Image("res/grass.png");
    stone = new Image("res/stone.png");
    dirt = new Image("res/dirt.png");
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) {

    for (int x = 0; x < map.size(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.get(x).size(); y++) {
            switch (map.get(x).get(y)) {
            case CLEAR:
                air.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case STONE:
                stone.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case GRASS:
                grass.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            case DIRT:
                dirt.draw(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

If anyone could help, that would be amazing!

Comment: Did you try set opacity false?

Comment: `public static final int CLEAR = 0, STONE = 1, GRASS = 2, DIRT = 3;` is much more concise

Comment: Sorry I'm using slick2d and its draw method is different than java 2d @Fess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding air rows then adding stone rows here:

```
for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> yaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        yaxis.add(CLEAR);
    }
    map.add(yaxis);
}

for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> yaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        yaxis.add(STONE);
    }
    map.add(yaxis);
}
```

The problem is that the stone tiles are out of the expected map size (32 x 24) because you've addded twice a much rows as you think you would.

Try replacing the list of lists by an array and you will see that you're going out of bounds.

Edit: here's a proper way to initialize your map with random data:

```
java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();

for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> yaxis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    map.add(yaxis);
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        yaxis.add(random.nextInt(4));
    }
}
```

Note that afterwards you won't be adding tiles, just changing the values, eg.

```
map.get(10).set(5, CLEAR);
```

Comment: Sorry I can't do that, I have to have to be able to remove tiles from the array, and an arraylist is the only way I could do it.

Comment: Even when sticking with lists, what you have here is a map that has 64 columns, not 32. The stone tiles are probalby out of the view.

Comment: How do you know that? Why would it be 64 and not 32? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Look at the code above, you're calling 'map.add(yaxis)' WIDTH times in two loops so the size of the map List is WIDTH * 2

Comment: I only have to call it once? I thought that since arraylists will shift numbers to fill holes, I would use yaxis to correct this. What would happen if I don't call it in each loop?

Comment: Every time you're calling 'map.add(yaxis)' you're adding a new column to the right of your map.

Comment: So I just cut that part out? Do I not need it?

Comment: You need to call 'map.add(yaxis)' 32 times, not 64 times. See the edit above

Comment: Ok thanks but do I add the random to each loop or just one? I'm a little confused as to why you can use random to do this, sorry...

Comment: The root of the problem is that you have two loops... You're adding 32 columns in the first loop, then 32 OTHER columns in the second one.

Comment: Yes I understand this. So just one for loop at the beginning?